# Print the consecutive 3 line at the pattern match

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a huge file where i need to sort and merge 3 line which are having pattern match "vm" and need them into One Single Line, like Below

kfg-ap4 is the Server name , we can have it Only Once that will be nice while sorting ..
I tried awk with getline but somehow i am missing to fit it ..

awk '/vm/ {printf $0 " ";getline; print $0}'  mem_overc

```
**[kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0**


[kfg-ap4] Executing task 'moc'
[kfg-ap4] sudo: /sbin/sysctl -A | grep overcommit
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
[kfg-ap4] out: Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out:     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
[kfg-ap4] out:     #2) Think before you type.
[kfg-ap4] out:     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out: sudo password:
```

> ```
> [kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0
> [kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
> [kfg-ap4] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
> ```

```
[kfg-ap4] out:
```

======================================================================

## Actual Data is as below and rest of the data is same except server names

```
[kfg-ap3] Executing task 'moc'
[kfg-ap3] sudo: /sbin/sysctl -A | grep overcommit
[kfg-ap3] out:
[kfg-ap3] out: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
[kfg-ap3] out: Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
[kfg-ap3] out:
[kfg-ap3] out:     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
[kfg-ap3] out:     #2) Think before you type.
[kfg-ap3] out:     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[kfg-ap3] out:
[kfg-ap3] out: sudo password:
[kfg-ap3] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0
[kfg-ap3] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
[kfg-ap3] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
[kfg-ap3] out:

[kfg-ap4] Executing task 'moc'
[kfg-ap4] sudo: /sbin/sysctl -A | grep overcommit
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
[kfg-ap4] out: Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out:     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
[kfg-ap4] out:     #2) Think before you type.
[kfg-ap4] out:     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[kfg-ap4] out:
[kfg-ap4] out: sudo password:
[kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0
[kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
[kfg-ap4] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
[kfg-ap4] out:
```

Comment: What is the Python issue?

Comment: @Trimax .. sorry for the confusion, i am trying to have any solution with awk,sed, python to solve this.. there is no issue with python

Comment: What part is the actual data and the expected result?

Comment: @James ..  The entire set having "[kfg-ap4]" Server name is the actual part of data from where we need to sort it.

Comment: OK, you only highlighted the lines you wanted printed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/vm/ {printf "%s%s", $0, (++i%3?OFS:ORS)}' log.txt
[kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
[kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_memory = 0 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 [kfg-ap4] out: vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
```

Walk-thru:

```
/vm/ {                                 # if vm on the record
    printf "%s%s", $0, (++i%3?OFS:ORS) # print record and OFS
}                                      # every 3rd time print ORS
```

Since there in fact was more that 3 rows in a group, use this:

```
$ awk '/vm/ {buf=buf OFS $0; next} buf!="" {print buf; buf=""}'
```

It buffers records and prints them out after it encounters a record that doesn't match `/vm/`. It may case a problem if you have consecutive groups in your file. You may end-up with longer-than expected lines.

```
$ cat > process.awk
/vm/ {              # if vm string in the record
    buf=buf OFS $0  # append the record $0 to the buffer variable buf
    next            # skip the rest of script for this record, ie.
}                   # only records without vm match get past this point
buf!="" {           # if the buffer is not empty
    print buf       # print it out
    buf=""          # empty the buffer
}
$ awk -f process.awk log.txt
```

Comment: Can you post some actual data, especially problematic parts?

Comment: Well, with data you posted I get 2 lines as output, 3 vm records on both.

Comment: Yes, that i can see, Thats nice, Can i attach the data file here to see more.. Thanks.

Comment: Put it in the Pastebin and post the URL.

Comment: There are groups that have more than 3 consecutive `vm` records. See another version in my answer.

Comment: Excellent James! Working Nice.

Comment: Can you break down for more explanation the code James if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there: Just accumulate in a variable and print in the end:

```
awk 'BEGIN{s="";} /vm/ {s = s $0 " "} END {print s}' log.txt
```

You can also use your exact construction and convert the newlines:

```
awk '/vm/ {printf $0 " ";getline; print $0}' log.txt | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: ..the above code is giving all the log.txt data into one line, i need to get each three lines when pattern matches and scale it down to the end of the file..So, 3 lines into one and then so on ...

Comment: You mean the 3 lines are consecutive, then

Answer (score 0):

Another answer using `sed` only

```
/vm/{
H
x
s/\n/ /g
s/ \[kfg-ap.\] out: / /
x
blab
}
x
p
:lab
```

invoke like this (save above file as `filter.sed`):

```
sed -n -f filter.sed text.txt
```

If `vm` is matched, then stores in the hold buffer. Then swaps the whole buffer to remove newlines and useless kfg prefixes in the line, swap again.

If not matched, swap the buffer again and print.

Rather simple & works great (cornercase: if log ends with the vm lines they may be omitted)

Comment: Thanks for the input Jean, this code works partially as it concatinates the expected lines but at the same time it produces the other output of the log file as well.. it we needs only lines matching /vm/, Thanks.

Comment: ok, that was just for fun playing with `sed`, and I did not understand fully your question. Since one answer was accepted, I won't dig in further unless you insist using cryptic `sed`